# Nested for loop in bash

Tags: bash

Hello I would like to ask you, how can I write the same exact loop in bash

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < a; j++) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + j);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: actually i tried for a in b yet.. i was not successful and i am a big beginner in bash

Comment: is this related to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291624/managing-the-number-of-lines-into-a-loop-function-from-a-textfile-in-shell-linux/291628#291628 ?

Comment: No sir, it is not related, i was actually trying to come up with two different versions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` supports C-style for loops as follows:

```
a=5 # example

for ((i = 0; i < a; i++)); do
  for ((j = i; j < a; j++)); do
    echo "$i $j"
  done
done
```

See here for more: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html